# Comparison between subsonic and ADO.NET Entity Framework which one is faster

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, subsonic

I am very confused with the use subsonic or ado.net entity framework Which one I should pefer? I creating a web site using asp.net mvc and all i need is greater performance and I also want to save time using ORM. So Which orm i should use?

Comment: Entity Framework is MUCH faster than Subsonic: http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2009/jun/entity_framework_vs_subsonic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perf is negligible when you're talking data access. I think you'll find that proper indexing, caching, and gzip compression will make all the difference. It's like asking which car to race at the Indy 500 and saying "I want the fastest" - there's a lot more to it (driver, conditions, parts, etc).

Comment: thanks can you give me suggestion in which scenario the subsonic will be better. My site will be a question answer site with the heavy database and user.

Comment: Isn't it possible to compare those two one the same machine / database?